# DJANGO - Upload an image file from directory to DB

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've Images in my project folder created automatically and I want to upload these images to my MySQL DB.
These images are named img0.png, img1.png.. etc

What I am currently doing :
**views.py**

```
for i in range(imageCount):
    img = open("img%s.png" %i)
    obj = userImages(userId = userid, images=img)
    obj.save()
```

**models.py**

```
class userImages(models.Model):
    userId = models.IntegerField()
    images  = models.ImageField()
```

**This doesn't work. How can I make it work??**

Comment: I'd suggest you to store the file in a different place (like a server, google storage or aws s3) and create a column to keep the path in the db... databases are not so great to keep files... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but is there any way I can make this work?
I want these images to be stored directly in the database.

Comment: I found this https://pynative.com/python-mysql-blob-insert-retrieve-file-image-as-a-blob-in-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

Databases are not a good place to put files in, please consider using s3 or cloud.

If you really want to save it on database use `BinaryField` but as the same [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield) is warning you that:

> Abusing BinaryField
>
> Although you might think about storing files in the database, consider that it is bad design in 99% of the cases. This field is not a replacement for proper static files handling.